# jdbc update query no working on unit test with derby database and SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

Tags: java, unit-testing, jdbc, derby, springjunit4classrunner

I am having problems trying to do an unit test.

**The test class is simple like:**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/job-runner-context.xml})
public class AtualizarDataServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    DataSource testDataSource;

    @Autowired
    Service service;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws DatabaseUnitException, SQLException{
        service.setDataSource(testDataSource);
    }

    @Test
    public final void testUpdateDate() throws SQLException {
        assertTrue(verifyDate());
        service.updateDate();
        assertFalse(verifyDate()); //Assert brokes here
    }

    private boolean verifyDate(){
        SimpleJdbcTemplate consultaTemplate = new SimpleJdbcTemplate(testDataSource);
        int count = consultaTemplate.queryForInt("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MY_TABLE");
        return count == 0;
    }
}
```

**The service:**

```
public class Service {

    private DataSource dataSource;

    public void updateDate(){
        SimpleJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new SimpleJdbcTemplate(getDataSource());
        String query = "UPDATE MY_TABLE SET DT_UPDATE_OPERATION = ?";
        jdbcTemplate.update(query, new Object[]{new java.sql.Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime())});
    }

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

}
```

`job-runner-context.xml` **important pieces:**

```
<context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="my.package"/>

    <bean class="my.package.Service"/>

    <bean id="testDataSource" class="com.read.only.MyBasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="jdbcReference" value="derby" />
    </bean>
```

**the jdbc connection properties:**

```
<com:jdbcReference name="derby" type="DATABASE">
        <com:credential user="" password="" />
        <com:autocommit arg="false" />
        <com:databaseConfig driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"
            url="jdbc:derby:dbderby;create=true" databaseName="ANY" />
    </com:jdbcReference>
```

At fist I thought the problem was related to commit issues but I tried set the value of autocommit properties to "true" and also manually call `testDataSource.getConnection().commit()` but it didn't work. The code and methods are working fine but the test isn't updating the derby database. In other test classes data is preset with `dbUnit` in the same database and the code works. This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259639/hibernate-not-inserting-data-into-derby-database-rows) gives an general list of possible problems I checked and I am reading and writing to the same tables in the same schemas. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259639/hibernate-not-inserting-data-into-derby-database-rows) to the question I posted I verified the autocommit and if I was writing to the right database, but didn't check the obvious: **you can't update a table with no registers!** The query `UPDATE MY_TABLE SET DT_UPDATE_OPERATION = ?` was applied to an empty table and the count query would always return 0. I just configured the test to make DbUnit import an state to the database from a xml file. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Try setup `<com:autocommit arg="true" />`.